# NGINX rewrite url with arg

Tags: nginx, rewrite

We need to check if a URL contains a specific arg "?___store=en" and then redirect to the same url, but add /en/ after the domain name. But this should be dynamic, because the url is not static and should be able to change from every specific page.

For example:

https://www.example.com/category1/product1?___store=en

Should be redirect to:

https://www.example.com/en/category1/product1

We already tried the following, but we are missing the dynamic part, because this rewrite to the homepage;

```
if ($arg____store = "en") {
    rewrite ^(.*) /en/? permanent;
}
```

Comment: Try: `rewrite ^/(.*)$ /en/$1? permanent;`

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks! Works perfect